# Regex to Find Only Exact matches of a number and exclude it when it's a substring of another number

Tags: regex

I have a string to be searched such as this:

"55 550 55.10 45.11 46 55 45 455"

I am searching for 55 and only want to return matches where the number is exactly 55. I case below, should only get 2 matches:

**55** 550 55.10 45.11 46 **55** 45 455

I have this regex:
`(55)+(?!\.)`

which yields FOUR matches. I don't want 550 or 455:
**55** **55**0 55.10 45.11 46 **55** 45 4**55**

I'm stuck with how to improve the regex so I only get the matches for the EXACT number.
Example:
https://regexr.com/7jhbo

Comment: Try: `(?<!\S)55(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other false positives you must consider, such as `6.55`.

Wrap your target in word boundaries, and add negative look behind/ahead for dot:

```
(?<!\.)\b55\b(?!\.)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/KNtxsOWvYMHXkV).